# how to create our own dataset for tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-lab, image-classification

I'm new at Tensorflow. I have large image dataset. And I'm  trying to create dataset for Tensorflow. I have searched a lot of resources but somehow couldn't implement on my dataset. Is there anyone who can help?

Comment: As it is, this question is much too broad. Perhaps you could elaborate on what your images are, what you want to do, etc.

Comment: my images are in jpg format. I want to classify my images which are not labeled. I tried to do this in traditional way but the kernel died, after researching I have learned that I have to do this with tf.data. but on the preprocessing part I am confused.

Comment: You don't *have* to use the tf.data API. Keras has a flow_from_directory command for images if they are stored on your hard drive in a folder. Still need more info: are the images all the same size, are you downsampling, etc.? While not relevant to your dataset creation, FYI, if you want to classify unlabeled images you either need to do a self-supervised approach or do some level of semi-supervised active learning.

Comment: Thank you for additional information. Images have the same size. I want to use the command you mentioned to store images, is that possible?

Comment: The flow_from_directory command is a generator that pulls images from disk, as they are needed, to feed into your model.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to do image classification?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to classify my images.